# NodeJS arrow keys don't work

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cmd, gruntjs, meanjs

I've been racking my brain lately with a kinda stupid problem. I'm using nodejs, more specifically... Using meanjs and I came across on this disturbing thing that doesn't allow me to use my key arrows. I use a command like "yo meanjs:angular-module test" and then appears some stuff to select, but, I can't move on the options because key arrows don't work. I've tried uninstall and install nodejs, update grunt, express, bower, everything! Not even on cmd from windows it works. Anybody have had this problem?

Comment: what do you mean using keys arrows? Where do you want to use the keys?

Comment: Did you try to use the number in front of yo options?

Comment: a--m - Using key arrows from the keyboard on node to choose what I want to include in my project(config, controllers, css...)

Scoupe - Yep, I did, no success.

Unfortunately I can't post pics yet, but what I wanted to show is this screen where I can't choose the options to include in my project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numbers, even if there are no numbered options.

I just had the same frustrating problem with "Feathers" API generator, while RDP'd to a Windows server from a Mac with a different language, so kind of expect these problems! Even though they don't have number prefixes, the number keys still select the options. Not sure if they are using yo to generate their app skeleton installer.

This question might be related depending on your OS. [How do I get the arrow keys recognized by Yo on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997336/how-do-i-get-the-arrow-keys-recognized-by-yo-on-windows-10)