# How do I get the arrow keys recognized by Yo on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-console, yo

I'm trying to run a `Yo` generator on my Windows 10 machine but it doesn't react when I press the arrow keys in order to select an option.
I found [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/strongloop/generator-loopback/issues/69) and tried to change `loopback:relation` but it didn't work for me. 
Maybe there's a new issue on Windows 10 only.

I also tried to go back to the legacy console but this this neither didn't solve the problem.

How do I get the arrow keys recognized by Yo on Windows 10?

Answer (score 4):

The bad news is that this is a bug on the node.js side with ongoing discussion on GitHub (Ex: https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/360). The good news is that I discovered a workaround for it...

When I use the yo generator for VS Code, for example, I am able to circumvent the problem by typing "yo" rather than "yo code." For some reason, typing just "yo" and then selecting the specific generator from the menu allows me to use my keyboard.

Until the bug is resolved, I hope this workaround helps you. Cheers!

Source: Personal testing on Windows 10 machine (Surface Pro 3) and yeoman yo CLI.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug at node js side. But you can use 1,2,3 to select menu item. Menu item is 1 based. In other words, press 1 to select the first menu item.

Answer (score 0):

This console emulator will have arrows working properly https://cmder.app/